# IPhone SDK File Will Not be Included

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have am trying to include a JSON parsing library into my app and I downloaded a JSON library from github, so I dragged the JSON directory into my Classes Folder in XCode and I can open up JSON.h fine and see all of its contents. But when I import it into my implementation file with this code:

```
#import "JSON/JSON.h"
```

I get a compile error saying JSON/JSON.h: No such file or directory

But I can see the file in my file browser in xcode!

This is the first time I've included another file like this :) Any advice would help!

Do I need to perhaps include it in my header file also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing just:

```
#import "JSON.h"
```

I believe Xcode just throws all the directories in your project into the header search path. You can check by looking at the actual commands being executed by Xcode during compilation.